# Customize Display of Linked doctype in form select

Tags: erpnext, frappe

How does one customize the fields being displayed in a form's link field selection.?

[image]

Answer (score 3):

Mostly this works by setting the "Search Fields" property of the DocType via **Customize Form**

This is a comma separated list of fieldname, like `item_name,description`

Comment: Could you elaborate a bit? For example, I want to change the fields that are being displayed for batch_no when adding an item to a Purchase Receipt. Which form do I customize?